# Out of Phonegap and PushBots, which one is more easier to implement push notification for ionic apps?

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging, pushbots

I am trying to learn the ionic framework to develop an android app. So, I wanted to know, out of Phonegap and PushBots, which one is more easier to implement push notification for ionic apps ? I am asking for easiness in terms of automatic setup and installation in existing ionic app and less errors and more tutorials. Those who have worked on them, please share your experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is much easier than Pushbots for ionic prospective. there are many tutorials are available for push notofocation by Phonegap.   https://thinkster.io/ionic-push-notifications-tutorial   try this...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to implement push notification a little bit using Phonegap but it is not going as per expectations. Like I tried with the tutorial given at http://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications/ , it looks very promising and there is a youtube video also, but on implementing, you get successfully built app with two buttons, one to identify user and second to register user, but none of the buttons are working, they just do not do anything.Just we can click them, that's it. My code and all implementations are exaclty as same on the website link.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/push-notifications-in-ionic-apps-with-google-cloud-messaging/    follow this tutorial

Comment: Yes, I have even gone through this tutorial and have already tried implementing it , but after setting up the ngrok server, I am not getting "device token received <<token value>>"  in the terminal window where I executed node ionic-gcm.js as the tutorial says.